# Using composite within a loop in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to use the Command Prompt in Windows 10 to run a loop on a batch of files in ImageMagick. As an example for a single image, the command I would use in IM is

```
 magick composite -geometry +5+10 imageA.png background.png
```

This works fine when I work with images individually.

However, I have a batch of 700+ images (let's call them `imageA.png`, `imageB.png`, `imageC.png`, `imageD.png`) and I want to overlay each of them onto `background.png`. I have tried using the following code:

```
 FOR %i IN (1) DO magick composite -geometry +5+10 *.png background.png %i_composite.png
```

This generates an output of one image, with each image overlayed on top of eachother. What I want to do is, for each `*.png` image in the directory `%i`, overlay it onto `background.png` and save it with the extension `filenumber_composite.png`.

For info, the loop works when I try to use a different kind of transformation (reducing the size of the image by a given %), but fails when I use the `composite` command.

Comment: Explain what the last three (file) parts of your command exactly doing

Comment: Have done that - hope this is clearer

Comment: Most of the folk on Stack Overflow, with a couple of exceptions, either know ImageMagick and never use Windows, or use Windows and don't know ImageMagick. Unfortunately, your question doesn't tell either of those types of people enough to work out the other half:-) Try showing a **single** ImageMagick command that does exactly what you want to one image - no loops, no variables, no asterisks - and also show a list of your filenames, then a Windows-y type of person will be able to help you,

Comment: Thanks! Ok, hopefully this will help...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "for" command is wrong. Try this with the "*.png" in the parentheses...

```
FOR %i IN (*.png) DO magick composite -geometry +5+10 %i background.png %i_composite.png
```

That means for each file in the group of *.png do the following action with "%i", which represents each one of those .png files in sequence.